# Bokeh graphs in HTML (with loop)

Tags: python, html, bokeh

I am trying to dynamically render bokeh graphs in HTML based on data that I pull from an SQL query.

I can make the graphs and render them in individual HTML files through Jupyter, but I struggle to do so from the actual code into my webpage.

Here the working code from Jupyter:

```
materialcode=cursor.fetchall()

    for number in range(0,len(materialcode),1):
        materialcode_list=materialcode[base_number+int(number)]['Material_Code']

        with connection.cursor() as cursor:
            sql = "Select Delivey_Date, Unit Price from report GROUP BY Delivey_Date";
            with connection.cursor(pymysql.cursors.DictCursor) as cursor:
                    cursor.execute(sql)
            linechart=cursor.fetchall()

        df=pd.DataFrame(linechart)

        x = df['Delivey_Date']
        y = df['Unit Price']

        p = figure(plot_width=750, plot_height=300, x_axis_type="datetime")
        p.line(x, y, line_width=2)
        p.title.text = df['Material_Name'][0]

        output_file("line"+str(number)+".html")
        show(p)
```

This generates multiple graphs each with their own HTML file (each popping up in a new window).
Now, I would like to render this in my HTML webpage, all graphs one below each-other in predetermined locations on the webpage.

For a single graph, this is easy Code as above except ending with the Bokeh js scripts and the script1=script1, div1=div1 references.

```
x = df['Delivey_Date']
y = df['Unit Price']

p = figure(plot_width=750, plot_height=300, x_axis_type="datetime")
p.line(x, y, line_width=2)


script1, div1 = components(p)
cdn_js=CDN.js_files[0]
cdn_css=CDN.css_files[0]

return render_template("Unit_price_graph.html",
script1=script1,
div1=div1,
cdn_css=cdn_css,
cdn_js=cdn_js,
data=data)
```

What I cannot figure out is how to include the scrips in the loop in order to automatically render each graph with its own script reference. I guess somehow there must be a way to construct the equivalent of output_file("line"+str(number)+".html") from the Jupyter example  for the script1=script1, div1=div1 needed for the Webpage.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

`components` can accept more than one thing at a time:

```
components({"Plot 1": plot_1, "Plot 2": plot_2})
#=> (script, {"Plot 1": plot_1_div, "Plot 2": plot_2_div})
```

See the [documentation](https://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/embed.html#components) for full details.

Comment: Thank you that is correct, however I am not generating 3 individual plots which I then display, I am creating a variable quantity of plots through a loop and somehow must be able replicate that loop also in the components.... that is where I am stuck. in the Jupyter Notebook this is solved through: output_file("line"+str(number)+".html").

Comment: Create the N plots in a loop keep them as you go, then pass them all to `components` at the end? That's what I would do based on your description here. Otherwise if you can't do that, call `components` in the loop with each single plot, then keep the `(script, div)` results to template at the end. There is no getting around having to keep track of either the plots, or the `components` output, until you can template at the end.

Comment: Thank you for your help, unfortunately I could not quite follow your suggested steps. I you could just reply with a minimum of corrected code, I would greatly appreciate.